# Port sharing in net tcp binding service

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-client, nettcpbinding

I have a site which uses nettcp binding service which is opened at port Number 808.

Now I have created one more website which uses nettcp binding at port number 808 only.

```
<endpoint address="net.tcp://ded3.demo.com:808/FileTransfer.svc">
<servicePrincipalName value="host/M04.ROUP.local" />
```

But the problem is whenever I run from the client ,the first service is getting called.

Please let me know how to give the correct endpoint address to call the corresponding services.

Comment: how are you hosting your site? IIS?

Comment: Yes the two sites are hosted in IIS only.  Programatically even the client's absolute URI is also correctly fetched .But later instead of hitting the second service ,it is calling the first service.One more interesting thing is If I change the port number to some other.eg:810 then the second service is rightly called..What could be the reason?

Comment: Are you running Net.TCP Port Sharing service?

Comment: Yes it is running and set to automatic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle this you'll need to turn on NetTCP Port Sharing. Open the services.msc, then find the Net.TCP Port Sharing Service, enable it, then turn it on. This should allow your IIS hosted tcp services to share the same port.

EDIT:
Given that you're already running Net TCP PortSharing, you may be running into a limitation of IIS. You'll need to either set up both services under the same site (but seprate applications), or use different ports. Take a look at this question for some more information:

[WCF net.tcp port sharing on IIS 7 / WAS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8531800/941243)

Comment: Yes Net tcp port sharing service is automatic and running.

Comment: Regarding the limitation of IIS,is there any documentation available from microsoft site?